# Spark DataFrame row count is inconsistent between runs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

When I am running my spark job (version 2.1.1) on EMR, each run counts a different amount of rows on a dataframe. I first read data from s3 to 4 different dataframes, these counts are always consistent an then after joining the dataframes, the result of the join have different counts. afterwards I also filter the result and that also has a different count on each run. The variations are small, 1-5 rows difference but it's still something I would like to understand.

This is the code for the join:

```
val impJoinKey = Seq("iid", "globalVisitorKey", "date")

val impressionsJoined: DataFrame = impressionDsNoDuplicates
  .join(realUrlDSwithDatenoDuplicates, impJoinKey, "outer")
  .join(impressionParamterDSwithDateNoDuplicates, impJoinKey, "left")
  .join(chartSiteInstance, impJoinKey, "left")
  .withColumn("timestamp", coalesce($"timestampImp", $"timestampReal", $"timestampParam"))
  .withColumn("url", coalesce($"realUrl", $"url"))
```

and this is for the filter:

```
val impressionsJoined: Dataset[ImpressionJoined] = impressionsJoinedFullDay.where($"timestamp".geq(new Timestamp(start.getMillis))).cache()
```

I have also tried using filter method instead of where, but with same results

Any thought?

Thanks
Nir

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"each run counts a different amount of rows on a dataframe"_? Is the source consistent, i.e. does _"read data from s3"_ give the same result between runs? Can you make sure that the number of rows per _"4 different dataframes"_ is consistent between runs? Print the counts after reading the dataframes and before using them.

Comment: Yes, the number of rows in the DF that reads from S3 are always consistent between runs, only the number of rows after the join is not consistent

Comment: Can you please show all of the code - including the counts you do? Also, what is this `impressionsJoinedFullDay` that is used in your filter function? Is that different from `impressionsJoined`??

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that one of the data sources changes over over time?
since `impressionsJoined` is not cached, spark will reevaluate it from scratch on every action, and that includes reading the data again from the source.

try caching `impressionsJoined` after the join.

Comment: The data on S3 does not change as I can see that printing out the count for the DF that read from s3 never changes. and also, the DF is already cached before the filter

Comment: Well, technically the same count for DFs read in only tells you that the number of rows are identical between runs - it does not guarantee that the data is the same. If you do not have full control over the data, please take a copy of the data and store it somewhere else on s3.